# What's a good icon to represent a legend or a key for a diagram?

Tags: html, user-interface, icons

I'm implementing a small web app widget that shows a legend/key for a diagram (or chart/map/graph/whatever), but only during mouseover of the widget. It's basically just going to be a div with a background image. What would be a good icon that communicates "I show the legend" or "I am the legend" to the unfamiliar users? I'm looking for something in the 10x10 to 20x20 pixel range.

Assuming that a legend is the same thing as a key (is it?) then I could use a small icon of a key (like you'd unlock a door with) but that seems cheesy or unclear at worst. I'm not sure that's really the clearest way to do it. Is there an icon that should instantly remind users of a legend?

Comment: http://www.dvdbeaver.com/film2/DVDReviews35/i%20am%20legend%20will%20smith/title%20i%20am%20legend.jpg  :)

Comment: When I think of legends, I think of Dan Marino, but a dolphin might not represent the right concept.

Comment: Use something with Will Smith that says "I am legend".

Comment: I think this is maybe a better question for doctype - it's not really a programming question

Comment: I've tried doctype for this sort of question before and it just hasn't been that useful.

Comment: ah, just goes to show, programmers are better than designers;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my region (southern USA) I would say the key is better known then legend. Thus I would find an icon of a key for this. There are many Icon sites one that I frequent is http://www.iconfinder.net/

Comment: It's not a very international solution though - in my region (Germany), "key" would make very little sense, because the translation "Schlüssel" can't be used for map or diagram legends.

Comment: This is for an intranet-only tool to be used (at least for now) only in the USA, so that's not a major concern. That said, I searched for "legend" on iconfinder and this might be just what I need: http://www.iconfinder.net/icondetails/21250/16

Comment: This is why engineers shouldn't do UI. I rest my case. :)

Answer (score 5):

Maybe just a question mark icon - help / legend are kinda similar on a map.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use an (i) icon for "info". Or maybe a [+] icon, that's often used to represent "more"

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'd use these directly, but maybe it'll spur some ideas.

[Info http://salamottawafm.files.wordpress.com/2009/02/info_icon.png?w=48&h=48](http://salamottawafm.files.wordpress.com/2009/02/info_icon.png?w=48&h=48)

[Compass http://kuaizhixin.cn/Writable/ClientImages/PageMenuLegendIconLw.bmp](http://kuaizhixin.cn/Writable/ClientImages/PageMenuLegendIconLw.bmp)

[RedDot http://www.cityofoaksmarathon.com/assets/images/icon_red-dot.png](http://www.cityofoaksmarathon.com/assets/images/icon_red-dot.png)

Comment: Your first icon here is what I am trying to describe in words below. I should have used 1,000 more!

Answer (score 1):

Something like a [tourist information sign](http://cache.virtualtourist.com/1269066-TOURIST_INFORMATION_SIGN-Zuberec.jpg) would probably be quite explicit to get information about an item...

Answer (score 1):

I agree with chris_l that the *i* icon would probably be what you want. I am making this my own answer because I disagree so strongly with his second suggestion (to use a + icon). The + icon is already understood to either add something or expand something, so I think the user would be confused. For legends in my own apps, I use a blue circle with an italic, lower-case "i" in white. Everyone seems to get it.

Comment: @Robusto: Okay, but wouldn't it expand something (the legend)? It's also used by Google Search this way, e.g. for the "Show options..." link on the top left.

Comment: @chris_l: That one *does* do an expansion, and more the point it has text next to it. It's not clear to me that the OP has any intention of having text with the link, so if an icon is to carry all the freight of meaning "see a legend" I think a simple plus falls woefully short. Expand something? Expand *what*, exactly? At least the circle-i lets you know there is going to be some meta-info available when you click it.

Answer (score 0):

At 10x10 or 20x20 pixels I think you're going to have to have something instantly recognisable. Don't over think this, if the obvious answer is a key, use a key