# What is more correct class name or object name in UML sequence diagram?

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

I was just wondering if it is more correctly to as a label of objects in UML sequence diagram instead of object name (which is irrelevant in my opinion and less informative than class name) provide class name. Another thing, while returning information instead of listing all objects names would it be a better solution to just write collection;

Diagram with object names:[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/934c6a3e87.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/934c6a3e87.png)

Diagram with class names:
[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/a44244eb7c.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/a44244eb7c.png)

As it's clearly visible from the second diagram that it is much more informative than the first one, and I think it is more practical.

Comment: I can't see them on mine either, but I assumed it was due to my company firewall.  The format for embedded images is correct.  Try updating the links between the parentheses.  You can use this SO post as a go-by:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587567/whats-a-good-icon-to-represent-a-legend-or-a-key-for-a-diagram/2587626#2587626

Comment: @atch: your first image is to a URL on your local system!

Comment: @John yes it was on local due to the fact that I was trying to figure-out why can't I see those images on my screen.

Comment: Images aren't displayed, or are sometimes not displayed. Try hosting the images on http://imgur.com/ which is the image host which SO would like to use by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sequence diagrams always represent interactions between objects. When showing the name of the object you can just use the object name (agreed, not useful in general), the syntax "object:class" (important when you are modeling a specific scenarion in which the name of the object is relevant to understand the scenario) or just " :class" (here you are using an anonymous object to indicate that the scenario applies to all objects of the class).

Comment: And what about the returning value? Do we have to list concrete values?

Comment: again, this depends on the importance of that value (e.g. if you use that as input of a call to another object further down in the diagram)

Comment: So basically what you're saying it isn't strict in a sense that you have just one way to present those things and you have some margin of freedom? Am I right?

Comment: Exactly. You can create sequence diagrams with different levels of detail.